# Update wordpress causes white space on admin

Tags: css, updates

I've updated wordpress to the 5.5 version, how can I remove this?

I've an empty div which has a **margin-top: 2rem**, which causes the white space on top, but can't explain for the footer

```
<div id="adminmenuback"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post: [How to fix the admin menu margin-top bug in WordPress 5.5?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372897/how-to-fix-the-admin-menu-margin-top-bug-in-wordpress-5-5)

There is no solution yet, but maybe this will help you find one.

Personally, I tested locally and on a SiteGround server, but I can't recreate the problem. However, if you can tell yourself it's a PHP error like the link I gave you above, maybe your file with PHP log errors will tell you something.

(Sorry for my bad english, j'ai voulu t'écrire en français, mais bon ^^)

Don't forget to write define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true) in your wp-config file.

Comment: Should've been more precise, WP_DEBUG is enable and WP_DEBUG_LOG is true

Comment: Put a look in your wp-content folder. If you have a PHP log error, you'll find the debug.txt file

Comment: Empty log, I'll wait for an update. thx