# WordPress admin menu gap when debug mode is enabled?

Tags: wp-admin, debug

After the recent update of WordPress, version 5.5.1.

Whenever I enabled the debug mode, there is a 2em gap between WordPress admin menu and the bar.

```
.php-error #adminmenuback, .php-error #adminmenuwrap {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Found out that this is showing because there is a hidden error somewhere on the website?

How I could show that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---Fix---

That CSS gap will only show when there is a "Hidden" error.

If these conditions are true,

```
if ( $error && WP_DEBUG && WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY && ini_get( 'display_errors' )
```

the gap will show, it means that **$error** variable is not empty, we should show the value in a log file.

To solve this issue, we need to show that hidden error by adding this code..

```
wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 201


$error = error_get_last();
error_log('===================This is the hidden error==================');
error_log(print_r($error,true));
error_log('=================Error Setting display======================');
error_log('WP_DEBUG');
error_log(print_r(WP_DEBUG ,true));
error_log('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY');
error_log(print_r(WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY,true));
error_log('display_errors ini setting');
error_log(print_r(ini_get( 'display_errors' ),true));
```

After checking the **debug.log**, we can now see and fix the error.

This is related to this issue [How to fix the admin menu margin-top bug in WordPress 5.5?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372897/how-to-fix-the-admin-menu-margin-top-bug-in-wordpress-5-5) and my answer also resolved it...

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is to enable [WP_DEBUG_LOG](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) in `wp-config.php`. The file will look like this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); //You may also set the log file path instead of just true
```

Defining WP_DEBUG_LOG as true will save logs under `wp-content/debug.log` and you'll find the PHP errors there.

Comment: No, this will not work, this is different from the recent update of Wordpress 5.5.1..

Comment: Which part will not work? What is the update in debugging?

Comment: This will not show "hidden errors" which is the cause of the gap from wp-admin main navigation. Please refer to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372897/how-to-fix-the-admin-menu-margin-top-bug-in-wordpress-5-5

Comment: Yes, this will not show the hidden errors but will log them into debug.log. This way you know what the errors are without exposing sensitive information to the public pages.

Comment: This has solved my issue like a charm. Thanks.